# MFC CListBox AddString - Prevent Automatic Sorting

Tags: c++, windows, sorting, mfc

Pseudo Code:

```
CListBox listBox;
CString[10] str; //consider it is initialised with valid string
for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
     listBox.AddString(str[i]);
```

Whenever I add an entry/string to a `CListBox` object using the function `AddString()`, the MFC `CListBox` sorts the entries automatically as each string is added.

How do I explicitly tell MFC to keep the items in the same order they are added (without sorting).

PS: I do NOT want to use the function `InsertString()` or so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Properties`tab there is a `Sort` property. Set it's value to `False`.

**Edit:**

As @The Forest And The Trees already mentioned, you could achieve same result from code:

`listBox.ModifyStyle(LBS_SORT);`

Comment: Additionally, if they're creating the CListBox programatically, they should make sure the `LBS_SORT` style isn't set.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks! I just made the changes using the Property Manager and set the Sort property to false.

Comment: 1) some style options don't work with `ModifyStyle`. For example, `ModifyStyle(LBS_SORT, 0);` does **not** work, because it cannot be modified after the listbox creation.  2) `ModifyStyle` needs more argument, such as `myListBox.ModifyStyle(WS_BORDER, 0, 0);`.